# IBM Cloud stable/mongodb chart with persistenceVolumeClaims

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to install [stable/mongodb](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb) helm chart to my cluster on IBM cloud. 
I followed [this guide](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-object_storage) for provisioning an object store service-instance, as well as configuring credentials and secrets.

Now I want to create a persistenceVolumeClaim and mount it to stable/mongodb installation. I tried creating the pvc by adding correct annotations to `persistence.annotations` values as provided by the stable/chart, however the annotations are not rendered as a part of the pvc. So then I first create a pvc successfully.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mongodb
  annotations:
    ibm.io/auto-create-bucket: "true"
    ibm.io/auto-delete-bucket: "true"
    ibm.io/bucket: ""
    ibm.io/secret-name: "cos-write-access"
  name: mypvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "10Gi"
  storageClassName: ibmc-s3fs-standard-regional
```

The pvc is bound

```
Name:          mypvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  ibmc-s3fs-standard-regional
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-74a512ea-875c-4d57-850f-2df599bff46a
Labels:        app=mongodb
               release=hasher
Annotations:   ibm.io/auto-create-bucket: true
               ibm.io/auto-delete-bucket: true
               ibm.io/bucket: 
               ibm.io/secret-name: cos-write-access
               pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ibm.io/ibmc-s3fs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      10Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From                                                                                                  Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----                                                                                                  -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning   53m   persistentvolume-controller                                                                           waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "ibm.io/ibmc-s3fs" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal  Provisioning           53m   ibm.io/ibmc-s3fs_ibmcloud-object-storage-plugin-c5dddccbd-dslv5_98f02393-5f15-11ea-aa3e-460564e82d0b  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/hasher-pvc"
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  53m   ibm.io/ibmc-s3fs_ibmcloud-object-storage-plugin-c5dddccbd-dslv5_98f02393-5f15-11ea-aa3e-460564e82d0b  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-74a512ea-875c-4d57-850f-2df599bff46a
```

Then I install the helm chart and pass the name of the pvc to the chart with 
`--set persistence.existingClaim=mypvc`.
But then the pod is continuously restarting, failing with the readinessProbe and error message:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
```

```
kubectl describe pod mongodb-pod

Name:         mdb-mongodb-5fc7f858d6-cz4s2
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         10.144.180.104/10.144.180.104
Start Time:   Fri, 06 Mar 2020 16:07:00 +0100
Labels:       app=mongodb
              chart=mongodb-7.8.7
              pod-template-hash=5fc7f858d6
              release=mdb
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: ibm-privileged-psp
Status:       Running
IP:           172.30.180.57
IPs:
  IP:           172.30.180.57
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mdb-mongodb-5fc7f858d6
Containers:
  mdb-mongodb:
    Container ID:   containerd://e563d7da6bfad26ece4b4bd8b0ba28774baf480c76c933610342eb097b8cf559
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.2.3-debian-10-r31
    Image ID:       docker.io/bitnami/mongodb@sha256:fc931d8dad56097d2d4d633f2d829b94a246d60652661b90d6e92432351e33f8
    Port:           27017/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 06 Mar 2020 16:07:04 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:      exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:            <set to the key 'mongodb-root-password' in secret 'mdb-mongodb'>  Optional: false
      MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY:     0
      MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG:       no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6:              no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB:  no
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-sdgp9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mypvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-sdgp9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-sdgp9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 600s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 600s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age   From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  21s   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/mdb-mongodb-5fc7f858d6-cz4s2 to 10.144.180.104
  Normal   Pulled     17s   kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Container image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.2.3-debian-10-r31" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    17s   kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Created container mdb-mongodb
  Normal   Started    17s   kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Started container mdb-mongodb
  Warning  Unhealthy  8s    kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Readiness probe failed: MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-06T15:07:13.382+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-03-06T15:07:13.384+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-03-06T15:07:13.384+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Logs:

```
 15:09:24.47 Welcome to the Bitnami mongodb container
 15:09:24.47 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb
 15:09:24.47 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/issues
 15:09:24.47 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
 15:09:24.48 
 15:09:24.48 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB setup **
 15:09:24.51 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MONGODB_* env vars...
 15:09:24.51 INFO  ==> Initializing MongoDB...
 15:09:24.52 INFO  ==> No injected configuration files found. Creating default config files...
 15:09:26.12 INFO  ==> Enabling authentication...
 15:09:26.13 INFO  ==> Deploying MongoDB with persisted data...
 15:09:26.14 INFO  ==> 
 15:09:26.14 INFO  ==> ########################################################################
 15:09:26.14 INFO  ==>  Installation parameters for MongoDB:
 15:09:26.14 INFO  ==>    Persisted data and properties have been restored.
 15:09:26.15 INFO  ==>    Any input specified will not take effect.
 15:09:26.15 INFO  ==> (Passwords are not shown for security reasons)
 15:09:26.15 INFO  ==> ########################################################################
 15:09:26.15 INFO  ==> 
 15:09:26.16 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
 15:09:26.17 INFO  ==> ** MongoDB setup finished! **

 15:09:26.19 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB **
2020-03-06T15:09:26.227+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2020-03-06T15:09:26.231+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/bitnami/mongodb/data/db 64-bit host=mdb-mongodb-5fc7f858d6-cz4s2
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian10
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-03-06T15:09:26.237+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-03-06T15:09:26.238+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "*", ipv6: false, port: 27017, unixDomainSocket: { enabled: true, pathPrefix: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp" } }, processManagement: { fork: false, pidFilePath: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb.pid" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, setParameter: { enableLocalhostAuthBypass: "false" }, storage: { dbPath: "/bitnami/mongodb/data/db", directoryPerDB: false, journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, logRotate: "reopen", path: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log", quiet: false, verbosity: 0 } }
2020-03-06T15:09:29.988+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1463M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-03-06T15:10:48.815+0000 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2020-03-06T15:10:48.815+0000 I  NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-03-06T15:10:48.815+0000 I  -        [signalProcessingThread] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-03-06T15:10:48.815+0000 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2020-03-06T15:10:48.815+0000 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
```

If I pass the `--set volumePermissions.enabled=true` the pod is stuck in PodInitializing state, and after a while with CrashLoopBackoff.

```
kubectl describe pod mdb-mongodb-6b99795f69-cchtm

Name:         mdb-mongodb-6b99795f69-cchtm
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         10.144.180.104/10.144.180.104
Start Time:   Fri, 06 Mar 2020 16:33:25 +0100
Labels:       app=mongodb
              chart=mongodb-7.8.7
              pod-template-hash=6b99795f69
              release=mongo
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: ibm-privileged-psp
Status:       Pending
IP:           172.30.180.58
IPs:
  IP:           172.30.180.58
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mongo-mongodb-6b99795f69
Init Containers:
  volume-permissions:
    Container ID:  containerd://23519443ca7d8ae5c980c4b51f5ed9e30ac03fff300471e26551078ee9f387b7
    Image:         docker.io/bitnami/minideb:buster
    Image ID:      docker.io/bitnami/minideb@sha256:2f430acaa0ffd88454ac330a6843840f1e1204007bf92f8ce7b654fd3b558d68
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      chown
      -R
      1001:1001
      /bitnami/mongodb
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 06 Mar 2020 16:33:53 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 06 Mar 2020 16:33:31 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 06 Mar 2020 16:33:52 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-sdgp9 (ro)
Containers:
  mongo-mongodb:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.2.3-debian-10-r31
    Image ID:       
    Port:           27017/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:      exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:            <set to the key 'mongodb-root-password' in secret 'mongo-mongodb'>  Optional: false
      MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY:     0
      MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG:       no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6:              no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB:  no
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-sdgp9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  mypvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-sdgp9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-sdgp9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 600s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 600s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age               From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----              ----                     -------
  Normal  Scheduled  36s               default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/mongo-mongodb-6b99795f69-cchtm to 10.144.180.104
  Normal  Pulling    9s (x2 over 32s)  kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Pulling image "docker.io/bitnami/minideb:buster"
  Normal  Pulled     8s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Successfully pulled image "docker.io/bitnami/minideb:buster"
  Normal  Created    8s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Created container volume-permissions
  Normal  Started    8s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, 10.144.180.104  Started container volume-permissions
```

Getting logs gives me the error message:

```
kubectl logs mdb-mongodb-6b99795f69-cchtm 
Error from server (BadRequest): container "mdb-mongodb" in pod "mdb-mongodb-6b99795f69-cchtm" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

I have tried setting it up with ceph object storage and it works fine right out of the box.
I do not understand where the issue lies and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Bitnami Engineer here. Could you create an issue github.com/bitnami/charts?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the interest. While I did figure out some of the issues, others have arisen. I have just submitted the issue on github: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/2084.